# DataBinding to Properties of related Tables in Winforms

Tags: c#, winforms, entity-framework

I'm trying to set up the data bindings for my WinForms controls. My intention was to load the table "tblAuftraegeDokumente" and then bind to some properties of its related tables. Sadly, this gives me an argument exception, saying that "ExterneNr" can't be bound.

The bindings are set up during the control load method, so I use a typeof(tblAuftraegeDokumente) as DataSource for my BindingSource since theres no real data loaded at this point. The code looks like this:

```
boundClaim.DataSource = typeof(tblAuftraegeDokumente); // dummy, real Datasource is loaded later

creationDateOutput.DataBindings.Add("Text", boundClaim, "TS");
creationUserOutput.DataBindings.Add("Text", boundClaim, "SUser");
externalNrInput.DataBindings.Add("Text", boundClaim, "tblAuftraegeReklamationen.ExterneNr"); // "can't bind to ExterneNr" exception here
```

Is there any way to do this without creating a second BindingSource for "tblAuftraegeReklamationen"?

Comment: What is `tblAuftraegeDokumente`? Entity class? Does it have navigation property called `tblAuftraegeReklamationen`? Showing the relevant part of the model would help getting answers.

Comment: Was going to post the relevant part and then saw the problem there, so thanks for the comment. Silly mistake. D;

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind,
tblAuftraegeDokumente and tblAuftraegeReklamationen had a 1-n relation, so this wasn't going to work. Changing it to a 1-[0,1] relation solves the problem, since the value for "ExterneNr" is unambiguous now.